# Python: how to go to the next line if you encounter a character within a line

Tags: python, io

I'm doing some I/O with Python. when reading from a file, i want the program to ignore the rest of the line and go to the next line if it encounters a semicolon (;). I have the following code but that only works if my line starts with a semicolon and not if the semicolon is some other place in the line. please help, thanks. 
CLARIFICATION: i want to then write each portion of the line without the semicolon to a new file line by line. basically i want to create a new file that does not have ";i want to ignore this bit" in it.

```
def ignoreSemi():
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            if char == ";":
                line = next(f)
```

Comment: The actual question is, why you want to ignore it? What is your goal in this program?

Comment: if you include content of file and expected output, it will be way clear to us

Comment: i made a clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generators, after_semi will produce parts of the line before the first semicolon

```
def after_semi(input):
    for line in input:
        yield line.split(';')[0]

with open('output', 'w') as f:
    for line in after_semi(input):
        f.write('%s\n', line)
```

Comment: for some reason this is counting several lines as one line sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the line by semicolon and handle the first part:

```
def ignoreSemi():
    for line in f:
        part = line.strip().split(';')
        do_something(part[0])
```

Comment: what does the part[0] mean?

Comment: @Chalupa split() returns a list, and [0] returns the first element.

Answer (score 0):

try like this: will give you line that not has ";"

```
def ignoreSemi():
    for line in f:
        if ";" not in line:
            # do your stuff
```

if you want to jump to next line if it encounters `;`:

```
def ignoreSemi():
for line in f:
    if ";" in line:
        line = next(f)
        # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't terribly clear.  Do you want to do something useful with characters prior to the semicolon? if so consider using line.split(";") and operating on the first member of the returned list.  If not try using something similar to the following:

```
def ignoreSemi():
    for line in f:
        if ";" not in line:
            [rest of loop here]
```

Comment: then splitting and using the first element of the resulting list is what you want.  The split operator will not include the semicolon character